# Parse error in response of AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am new to javascript and jquery, in my code I'm initiating a AJAX call and I get the following response.

[image]

I'm trying to implement an autocomplete functionality. I am using below code to do AJAX call.

```
$( "#city" ).autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
        jQuery.ajax({
          url: "the url",
          data: {SearchTerm: request.term}
          success: function (data) {
               console.log("the data is" +data); 
               response(data);
            }
        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
             console.log("failure1" + textStatus);
             console.log("failure2" + jqXHR.status);
    });
      },
      minLength: 3,
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        console.log( ui.item ?
          "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
          "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
      },
      open: function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
      },
      close: function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
      }
    });
  });
```

Even though I see 200 response from the server and the response in JSON format, success method doesn't get called and fail get called. Since I'm getting JSON response with 200 status, doesn't success method should get called?

Comment: It's invalid JSON.  Your server-side component (ViewCustomers?) is escaping all the quotes.

Comment: Thanks james. I'm sorry, can you please tell me how this JSON response should look?

Comment: `{"suggestions": ["name1", "name2", "name3"]}`

Comment: Another doubt I have it, the server automatically adds the escape character when I send json from server to client. Is there a way to prevent this? I'm sending the response in {"suggestions": ["name1", "name2", "name3"]} format

Comment: Fix your server code to produce valid JSON.  That is all.

Comment: You can see my answer :) That might be helping you..

Answer (score 0):

Try this, may be this will help you :

**Option 1 :**

*May be you accidently turning On **Magic Quotes** in PHP*

*But this function is already deprecated in PHP 5.3.0.*

*And REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0. as mentioned in [here](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc)*

- Go to your php.ini file
- Search this keyword : *`magic_quotes_gpc`*
- Set it to OFF : *`magic_quotes_gpc = Off`*

**Option 2 :**

*Do it on your code like this :*

> ```
> if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
>     $returnedValue = stripslashes($yourReturnedValue);
> }
> ```